# Django 1.7 conflicting models

Tags: django, django-models, python-module

I install my application in "project/apps/myapp" folder. Both apps and myapp folders have **init**.py files(Without any of them there is module missing error).  Now I've the error:

```
Exception Type: RuntimeError at /
    Exception Value: Conflicting 'person' models in application 'resume': <class
 'apps.resume.models.Person'> and <class 'resume.models.Person'>.
```

Django import the same model with two different pathes. How can I fix it?

Full error log:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/voxa/django/FortyTwoTestTask/fortytwo_test_task/urls.py" in <module>
  4. from resume import views
File "/home/voxa/django/FortyTwoTestTask/apps/resume/views.py" in <module>
  4. from resume.models import Person
File "/home/voxa/django/FortyTwoTestTask/apps/resume/models.py" in <module>
  3. class Person(models.Model):
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __new__
  285.         new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)
File "/home/voxa/.virtualenvs/42-test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py" in register_model
  213.                 (model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /
Exception Value: Conflicting 'person' models in application 'resume': <class 'apps.resume.models.Person'> and <class 'resume.models.Person'>.
```

Comment: Do you have the "resume" app both at _project/resume_ and _project/apps/resume_?

Comment: no only "project/apps/resume"

Comment: Can you do `from apps.resume.models import Person as Person1; from resume.models import Person as Person2; print Person1.__file__; print Person2.__file__` and post the results here?

Comment: Same issue for me, did you solve it?

Comment: I solve this problem as Wangolo Djoel described in his answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of importing the all project then the app then the module inside the app just import the app which is inside the project then the module.

Instead of

```
from webproject.app import model
```

Use

```
from app import model
```

or

```
from app.models import Staffs
```

Answer (score 5):

I think [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22280) (turns out it's a feature) is related to your problem.

For me the problem was resolved by importing from `resume.models` only, rather than `apps.resume.models`. So search for `"from apps."` in your project and replace it.

(For me, removing `__init__.py` or changing the `PYTHONPATH` caused other problems, I imagine that's common.)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a century, but here goes my solution that was really painful to find.
Given this project tree:

```
repo
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── project
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── ...
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── mymodel.py
.   .   .   ...
```

Besides having the `core` folder included in the `PYTHONPATH`, there were places where I was doing `from ..models import MyModel`.

Apparently, using relative imports (`..models`) was in some way generating the path from the repo folder `app`, this is `app.core.models`.

When running the tests, it assumed a duplication through sometimes refering the the same model in both paths: `<app.core.models.MyModel>` and `<core.models.MyModel>`, so I opted for using `core.models` instead of `..models`.