# Upgrading from Django 1.6.7 to 1.8.3, RuntimeError: Conflicting models in application

Tags: python, django, django-models, upgrade, django-1.8

I'm using Django 1.8.3 and Python 2.7.6

```
My project structure:
project/
   __init__.py
   app/
      __init__.py
      sa1/
         __init__.py
         admin.py
         models.py
         interface.py
      sa2/
         __init__.py
         forms.py
         urls.py
         views.py
      app/
         __init__.py
         admin.py
         models.py
         tests.py
         views.py
```

I tried to import models in sa2/forms.py as follows:

```
from project.app.sa2.models import Mo1, Mo2, Mo3
```

This raised an error -

```
Exception Type: RuntimeError at /
    Exception Value: Conflicting 'mo1' models in application 'app': <class
 'project.app.models.Mo1'> and <class 'app.models.Mo1'>
```

I've tried to solve it using: [Django 1.7 conflicting models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591399/django-1-7-conflicting-models)

So, I Changed it to:

```
from app.sa2.models import Mo1, Mo2, Mo3
```

This raised an error => `ImportError: no module named sa2`

So, I took another approach by getting rid of `__init__.py` in project/ as mentioned in https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22280

This raised another error => `ImportError: No module named project.website.settings`

Please help me debug this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the some problem. From within **sa2** try

```
from sa2.models import Mo1, Mo2, Mo3
```

or alternatively

```
from .models import Mo1, Mo2, Mo3
```

***CATCH***: be sure to use the same imports in your forms.py, tests.py or wherever else you import those models. If you update only one of the import it will not work and you will still get the same error.

The problem occurs because of a double import. For more information please see this : [The Double Import Trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap)

Good luck

P.S. no `__init__.py` were hurt in the process

Answer (score 0):

Remove `__init __.py` file in project folder. I have same error when use test in Django and then I remove it, error is disappear.