# django signals on inherited profile

Tags: python, django, signals

I have User model and a user can be of type 1 or 2.
Depending on what type of user is created, I want to associate a profile to the model. If type 1, it will be a Person, and type 2 a Company.

I have tried writing the code in models.py and also following the tutorial : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

signals/apps/entitiesmodels.py

```
class CompanyModel(AuditedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)

class PersonModel(AuditedModel):   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)

class Tester(PersonModel,PersistentModel):
    # Link with user
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_user')

class Company(CompanyModel,PersistentModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_user')
```

signals/apps/entities/signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver          
from django.conf import settings              

from . import models as entities_models       

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def user_create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.user_type == 1:
            entities_models.Tester.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.user_type == 2:
            entities_models.Company.objects.create(user=instance)
        else:
            pass
```

signals/apps/entities/app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class EntitiesConfig(AppConfig):
    name ='entities'

    def ready(self):
        import entities.signals
```

signals/apps/entities/api_v1/views.py

```
from signals.apps.entities import models           
from . import serializers                          
from signals.libs.views import APIViewSet          

class PersonViewSet(APIViewSet):                                                             
    queryset = models.Person.objects.all()         
    serializer_class = serializers.PersonSerializer
```

signals/apps/entities/api_v1/urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from signals.apps.entities.api_v1 import views

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
app_name='entities'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'persons', views.PersonViewSet, base_name="entities-persons")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

settings.py

```
LOCAL_APPS = (                                   
    'signals.apps.authentication',               
    'signals.apps.entities.apps.EntitiesConfig', 
)
```

When running server, the error is:

```
 File "/home/gonzalo/Playground/signals3/signals/signals/apps/entities/api_v1/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
   from signals.apps.entities.api_v1 import views
 File "/home/gonzalo/Playground/signals3/signals/signals/apps/entities/api_v1/views.py", line 1, in <module>
   from signals.apps.entities import models
 File "/home/gonzalo/Playground/signals3/signals/signals/apps/entities/models.py", line 47, in <module>
   class Person(PersonModel):
 File "/home/gonzalo/.virtualenvs/signals-test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
   "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
untimeError: Model class signals.apps.entities.models.Person doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

I have the example code on github if someone wants to check it out :  https://github.com/gonzaloamadio/django-signals3

Comment: Your problem is probably the same as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29272675/9794932 but it is hard to know exactly without working through your github. If you could post the particular pieces of the code where the problem occurs (i.e. quote a minimal broken example in your post) it might be easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank for the answer, when using that way of referring an app on settings, then you should use the import like this:

signals/apps/entities/api_v1/views.py

```
from signals.apps.entities import models
```

and in urls.py

```
from entities.api_v1 import views
```